# I need help in understanding the following code

Tags: solidity

In the following code I am getting the following error when I declare selfdestruct() function in this code.

Error is :

```
Invalid implicit conversion from address to address payable requested.

pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

    contract owned{
        address owner;
        constructor() public{
            owner = msg.sender;
        }
        modifier onlyOwner{
            require(owner == msg.sender);
            _;
        }
    }
    contract mortal is owned{
        function close()public onlyOwner{
            selfdestruct(owner);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using version 0.5.x of the Solidity compiler, `selfdestruct` accepts an `address payable`, but you're passing in an `address`.

You can fix this by just changing the type of `owner`:

```
address payable owner;
```

But your pragma directive is a crazy range... there's no way to make this code work with both 0.4.x and 0.5.x compilers. There were quite a few breaking changes between those versions (including this one).

Comment: Sure Thank you I will change my compiler version and compile it.